How to return in an Async Function in Angular?
I am getting an error when adding an if else condition inside the async function in Angular. I need to have a return to avoid the error in my async function

  asyncFunction: (value) => {
      if (value.includes('SAMPLESTRING')) {
        const getApplication = this.myService.getApplication({ id: value })
        .pipe(map(({ Application }) => Application))
        
      } else {
        const getApplication = this.myService.getApplication({ name: value })
        .pipe(map(({ Applications }) => Applications))
      }  

      return getApplication;
    }


The getApplication variable is in the if and else block scope. You can't access it outside of the scope.

If I use let outside the if else block, I get this error:
Type '(value: string) => Observable | Observable<ServiceNowBusinessApplication[]>' is not assignable to type '(value: string) => Observable<ServiceNowBusinessApplication[]>'.
Type 'Observable | Observable<ServiceNowBusinessApplication[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ServiceNowBusinessApplication[]>'.

Check out my answer. Also there is a typo error in your code. Based on you screenshot, your else block should call getApplications method. Currently, you are calling the same method in if and else.

As mentioned currently the getApplication variable is defined in the if and else block and you can't access it outside of the scope,
you should declare the variable outside of the block scope.
asyncFunction: (value) => {
  const getApplication: Observable<Application[]> = of([]); 

  if (value.includes('SAMPLESTRING')) {
    getApplication = this.myService.getApplication({ id: value })
      .pipe(map(({ Application }) => [Application]))    
  } else {
    getApplication = this.myService.getApplication({ name: value })
      .pipe(map(({ Applications }) => Applications))
  }

  return getApplication;
}


if (value.includes('SAMPLESTRING')) {
return  this.myService.getApplication({ id: value })
.pipe(map(({ Application }) => [Application]))
}
return  this.myService.getApplication({ name: value })
.pipe(map(({ Applications }) => Applications))
Would be much less verbose I think.
